# MS SQL FileSize and MD5 vs straigh MD5 seek

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, hash

Suppose I have table of files:

```
Id FileSize MD5
1  100      0x111324B043546BED2035965E9A091E11
2  200      0x222324B043546BED2035965E9A091E22
```

And my task is to find Id by provided FileSize and/or MD5 in most effiecient way (sometime only hash available, but some time size available too). Hash is unique, even if it possible to create same hash for different files, we don't count this case.
I can do this through **EF 6**:

```
var file = ctx.Files.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.FileSize == fileSize && x.MD5.Equals(md5));
```

but also this possible:

```
var file = ctx.Files.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.MD5.Equals(md5));
```

Which one will be most efficient and fast? Should I write straight SQL query or do something else to increase performance of file retrieval by hash?

Basically, I want to maximize performance of key-value dictionary, but don't know where to start.

Comment: Did you already profile and found this query to be the bottleneck? Most likely the query won't matter as much as your DB schema/keys/indexes. But unless you profiled and found this to be an actual problem I wouldn't care.

Comment: Well, Im not so much of SQL expert so don't know how to profile properly query by query. Not even coded this example. The problem is, this table will be storing gazillions of rows and will be accessed all the time, so this is mainly the reason I care about fast key-lookup.

Comment: If you have unique index on hash - it doesn't matter, because filesize constraint is irrelevant. If you don't have such index - still doesn't matter, because server will have to loop over all rows to find an item. Only difference might be if you have index on filesize but not on hash.

Comment: Oh, thats cleared things up in my head a little. So FileSize do not counted when lookup is made (not helping for faster find).

Comment: Well if there cannot be situation when hash matches and size does not - then size is irrelevant (and I cannot imagine such situation). I suggest filling your table with gazillion rows with random data, then create unique index on hash, then make a query and see if perfomance satisfies you.